# cpp_bin_float not found between boost library

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu, boost, compiler-errors

I'm using boost library to handle big numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/number.hpp>

namespace mp=boost::multiprecision;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
typedef mp::number<mp::backends::cpp_bin_float<2000> > cpp_bin_float227;
    cpp_bin_float227 b = 998;
   std::cout << std::numeric_limits<cpp_bin_float227>::digits << std::endl;
   cout<<std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<cpp_bin_float227>::max_digits10)<<pow(b,9999)<<endl;
}
```

But I got this error at compile-time:

```
fatal error: boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>
```

If I use cpp_dec_float instead of cpp_bin_float it works fine.
Why is the library not found and how to fix it?

(I'm using c++11 compiler, in Ubuntu)

SOLUTION:
The problem was that in answe, namely aold version of boost library.
Minimal version to support cpp_bin_float is 1.58

Remove current version with:

```
apt-get --purge remove libboost-dev libboost-doc
```

Later I installed version 1.63 (isn't the latest that is 1.64) following

```
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/boost.html
```

Comment: We can't tell. You need to post the compiler flags, look at `g++ -v` to see what include paths are used. On my ubuntu the headers are in package `libboost1.58-dev` (libboost1.58-dev_1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb installable by the generic package `apt install libboost-dev`)

Comment: @sehe I added output of g++ -v  in the question

Comment: I mean when compiling. And it's _you_ who should do the checking of the include paths reported.

Comment: @sehe In /usr/include/boost/multiprecision there are cpp_dec_float.hpp and others but there isn't cpp_bin_float.hpp   How can add, togheter its dependencies?

Comment: Just fix the install. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall` (packagename, like `libboost-dev`)

Comment: @sehe Which version I have to install? What is the exact command that I have to give?

Comment: I already told  you. How can I /know/ your OS/distro/repo package versions? Just type it in. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libboost-dev`. If you wanna be sure, you can just uninstall it first.

Comment: Version of boost is should be 1.54.0.1ubuntu1.  However I did that you told, I given the above command but later the problem remains. What could I do to solve it?

Comment: @sehe With your command there was not nothing update, nothing deleted, nothing installed, one alone reinstalled

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version of boost doesn't have `cpp_bin_float`. It's also seriously old.

See it live:

- boost 1.54 https://wandbox.org/permlink/7MQy5HR90GB0GbVt
- boost 1.55 https://wandbox.org/permlink/nPOH5kDRCq1PUXWl
- boost 1.56 https://wandbox.org/permlink/IhClSKBx0k0pSVUe OK!

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your help. Thus, I have to install a new recent version of boost library. There is a way to do it quickly? (I suppose that first I have to delete current boost version also)

Comment: I'm sure there are previously asked questions about this